# tkinter askopenfilename doesn't allow multiple file selection

Tags: python, tkinter

All references I can find for `askopenfilename` suggest that it should allow me to open multiple files within the dialog.  Unfortunately that is not working for me.  I'm running this under Python 2.7.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

filenames = askopenfilename(parent=root,filetypes=[("CSV Files",".csv")])
```

Both Ctrl and Shift left-mouse do not change the behavior

Enlightenment is most appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Apologies all.  I'll blame this on a lack of caffeine.

The command should be askopenfilename**s**

Answer (score 0):

use `multiple=True` as below,

```
filenames = askopenfilename(parent=root, multiple=True, filetypes=[("CSV Files",".csv")])
```

for reference: https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-filedialog-upload-display.php